# Should I Alternate My PPL Workout To Avoid Adaptation?

Tags: workout-routines, splits

I've been doing PPL / Rest(yoga) / PPL 6 days a week for the last 2 months. I absolutely love this program and I made a lot progress during it. My question is should I start alternating my reps/sets or switch to completely different workout program to avoid adaption? I'd love to continue my program as it is but everybody says it's a bad thing and hinder my results. What do you think?